Is there a way to download all data containing amino acid sequence - secondary protein structure from protein data bank
Is there a way to download all data containing amino acid sequence - secondary protein structure from protein data bank(https://www.rcsb.org/).
Or is there a way to extract the data programaticaly using some api.

This download information page was linked from the page you referenced (Download -> File Download Services):
https://www.rcsb.org/docs/programmatic-access/file-download-services
This page also contains links to download other related information, for example a list of all PDB IDs:
https://data.rcsb.org/rest/v1/holdings/current/entry_ids

The PDB archive is maintained by the wwPDB at the main archive, files.wwpdb.org (data download details) and the versioned archive, files-versioned.wwpdb.org (versioning details).
All data are available via the HTTPS protocol.

There is also API information here (Download -> Web Services):
https://www.rcsb.org/docs/programmatic-access/web-services-overview

All static data that is exposed in rcsb.org is available in the Data API. The schema follows the mmCIF dictionary, extended with annotations coming from external resources. The core PDB data is split up into core objects, one per level of the structural data hierarchy, with entity subdivided into polymeric and non-polymeric subschemas (differing from the mmCIF dictionary).

